# Two parallel TransactionScope each with it's own connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, transactionscope

I'm trying to figure out how TransactionScope works playing around with sample code representing different transactions scenarios...
Can you explain what actually happens with date when I have 2 concurrent TransactionScopes each with it's own connection? Like in this sample code:

```
internal class Program
{
    private const int Count = 20;
    private static readonly Random Random = new Random();

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task1 = new Task(Task1);
        var task2 = new Task(Task2);
        task1.Start();
        task2.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static void Task1()
    {
        var connection = new EntityConnection("name=ModelContainer");
        using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
        {
            DoWork(connection);
            transaction.Complete();
        }
    }
    private static void Task2()
    {
        var connection = new EntityConnection("name=ModelContainer");
        using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
        {
            DoWork(connection);
            transaction.Complete();
        }
    }
    private static void DoWork(EntityConnection connection)
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var context = new ModelContainer(connection))
        {
            List<SyncData> list = context.SyncDataSet.ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
            {
                list[i].Knowledge.Version = Random.Next(200);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transaction scopes that are *nested* (and on the same thread) become part of the same transaction (the outer transaction being the defining scope for completion) - escalating to DTC if needed. In your case the transactions don't seem nested, so they are unrelated. That should also mean that the LTM rather than DTC is the owner, which has less overhead.

As a result, of course, you may need to watch for blocking etc between these if they touch the same data. Especially since transaction scope defaults to serializable isolation.

Comment: They are unrelated yes, but what is happening with data here? In theory transactions are isolated so the first transaction should create "db copy" and modify this copy, right after first transaction creation, second is created and should have same data copy, because it is created before 1st commit. Then 1st commit it's data, and then second commit it's data, so basically I should have in result the data of the last transaction to commit, but in this code the result is dead lock.

Comment: @Broken indeed; the *read* here is just a read lock so deadlock is likely. If I was writing TSQL I would add the UPDLOCK which would cause blocking rather than deadlock. I don't know if you can add UPDLOCK to reads with EF

Comment: @Broken re the scenario - the first commit can't happen if the second thread has a read lock. The UPDLOCK suggestion above would work by *preventing* the second thread from reading the data until the first thread has finished it's work.